# Autosaving a workbook

Tags: vba, userform, autosave

I need help with my VBA. I have a shared workbook on a shared drive. Since I use a userform that copies all data entries on a worksheet, I use

```
If ThisWorkbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    ActiveWorkbook.AcceptAllChanges
    End If
```

to make sure that file is saved first before copying data entries to avoid saving conflicts from all the users. But when ever the the userform is active but a different workbook is open(main workbook is minimized) this error appears:

> Run-Time error '1004': Method 'AcceptAllChanges' of object_Workbook'
>   failed

is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Could be the `ActiveWorkbook` causing that but this is just a wild guess what's the code wrapping that?

Comment: Well i tried replacing it with ThisWorkbook.AcceptAllChanges and its still the same error

Comment: Hmm. can you try remove the shared feature off the workbook?

Comment: Yeah I can but unfortunately it has to be a shared file.

Comment: shared files do not restrictions on macros... i haven't find anything online on your error